# Calculate the probability that no two of three people have the same birthday

Tags: probability, birthday

Hello I would like for your guidance to the following problem:

There are 3 people. We would like to calculate the probability that no two of these people have the same birthday.

The probability is $(364/365)( 363/365)$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: The double-negative is potentially confusing.  "none does not", means "every single one does".  Is that your intended meaning?  Then the answer to that would be $365^{-3}$ assuming not a leap year.  But I don't think you intended the double-negative.

Comment: Thank you very much